# Is it possible to let Doctrine convert JSON object to php array using plain SQL?

Tags: mariadb, doctrine

I want to use Doctrine to execute a plain SQL-query on a MariaDB-database containing a JSON_OBJECT()-call in the SELECT-clause similar to this:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT 
        JSON_OBJECT(\'id\', id, \'name\', name) as employee,
        ...
    ...
';
```

The result is retrieved by executing

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->executeQuery()->fetchAllAssociative();
```

This yields an associative array `["employee" => "{"id": 123, "name": "The name"}"]` where the value of "employee" is encoded as a string.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to convert the retrieved value to a php-array instead?